# Type unsafety: Unchecked cast from Foo to Bar. JPA stuff

Tags: java, jpa, warnings, openjpa, type-safety

I am using openJPA (a bit old version 1.2) and I get warnings every time I cast `query.getResultList()`. I use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in the previous line so I can get rid of that specific warning but I cannot do the same when I need to return the list like in the following example:

```
// @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") I DON'T WANT TO DO THIS HERE
public <T> List<T> findByQuery(String queryString) {
    myEntityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // I WANT TO DO IT HERE
    return (List<T>)query.getResultList();
}
```

Here I could do:

```
    ...
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<T> result = query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

but then [sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) complains that I should not store the list in a variable but return it inmediately. What is my best option here?

Comment: As you are returning the value from the method without assigning it in the first snippet, you have to add @SuppressWarnings to the method itself. You have to live either with sonar violation or first code snippet with "I DON'T WANT TO DO THIS HERE"

Comment: Just to fool around sonar there is a dirty solution as well (Although i do not recommend doing this). Add "result.size();" before returning the result to get rid of sonar violation. I recommend stick to 1st snippet with annotation at the method level.

Comment: Doesn't sonar use Checkstyle? You can disable the checkstyle error.

Answer (score 0):

`query.getResultList()` returns `List<Object>`. You wan't to cast it to `List<T>` but java cannot define is it possible or not - due the type erasure there is no difference beetween them in runtime. That's why you have to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

There is one simple solution to get rid of this - cast all the objects to desired type in new function. To do this, you have to now what class is it - so:

In java 8

```
public <T> List<T> findByQuery(String queryString, Class<T> clazz) {
    myEntityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    return query
           .getResultList()
           .stream()
           .map(result -> clazz.cast(result))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In older versions of java you just change map function to simple loop putting casted results in new `List<T>`

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList())` will return `List<T>` with mapped results. Consider it as some kind of `reduce()` method

Comment: yeah... I thought that. I just want to cast. If I need to create a new array to get of rid of the warning then I think I should prefer @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") at method level.

Comment: I think there are no other options.